# AWS DynamoDB Export to S3-Creating empty files

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am using export to S3 feature of DynamoDB to export table data to S3 bucket. I observed that export is creating empty files in s3 bucket along with actual data. How can I prevent that?